# The Maze of Text

Tags: word-search

Just follow the maze.

```
I IIIIIIII
I IIIIIIII
I     IIII
IIIII IIII
IIIII IIII
III   IIII
III IIIIII
III IIIIII
III      
IIIIIIIIII
```

And here's another set of text required to solve this

```
AYIFIEWIIE
XOCOIEHIUW
YUCOMPHFBW
CNITPLYRNI
JLMHDEPTVD
LIFDETFJEU
PMBTOIJFIO
TIVHIHIJWE
IRQISMAZES
GWCSDFUKIL
```

Hint:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg

Comment: This is *way* too easy.

Comment: I'm not sure this could have been made easier.  Perhaps,  `Type: "YOU COMPLETED THIS MAZES"`

Comment: +1. to all downvoters: A puzzle being very easy is NOT a reason to downvote!

Comment: A puzzle being low quality, however, is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the path required to complete the maze on the block of text gives you the answer

> YOU COMPLETED THIS MAZES

Comment: Once I can actually accept your answer, I will do it. Congratulations on doing it so quickly.

Comment: @Peanut why the "s" at the end ?

Comment: Normally it wouldn't be there, but the text was one letter short for the maze.